# Props fallthrough would not work on a component build on top of another component

Tags: vue.js

I have built a user-defined component (`async-select`) on top of another component ([vue mutliselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/)) like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/hmds2n6L/4/

I have heard about VueJS feature called `props fallthrough` that means that the child component should inherit all the props of the parent component. For example, `multiselect` should inherit the `loading` prop of . However, we see that the `loading` prop is not passed to `multiselect` which can be seen from the fact the loader is not visible.
In contrast, if I move the `loading` prop from `async-select` right to the `multiselect` component like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/hmds2n6L/1/

then everything works just fine.
Am I misunderstanding the prop fallthrough concept ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such automatic prop fall-through concept and components don't automatically pass on their props to all of their children (this would be bad.)  However, you can implement this behavior by rebinding all of the `$attrs`:

```html
<multiselect
   v-bind="$attrs"
   :options="[]">
</multiselect>
```

This does rebind the wrapper props to the child component.  Here is your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/dmh3q8po/)

Comment: Can you say that it's anti-pattern ?

Comment: It's ok to use.  Here is a [comment](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/implementing-v-bind-attrs-using-a-render-function/27857/3) from a Vue team member / forum leader about it

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding (based on the link to the library docs) that the OP was referring to Vue2. As such, the accepted answer is valid.

For those reading this post developing with Vue3 the answer is now different.

Props fall through deeply via something they refer to as "Nested Component Inheritance."

Please see the [docs for more information.](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#nested-component-inheritance)